# How do I keep correct information in updatable textboxes when updating a pivot table?

Tags: excel

So my situation is that I am trying to create a set of textboxes that are in a figure that represent a set of information that are easily updatable but the problem is that since I am using a pivot table to organize the information and get rid of replicates, that when the pivot table is updated, these textboxes start displaying incorrect information.

In the example I have put together (the first image being the initial situation, and the second image being after the pivot table is updated) the first part of the figures in supposed to be the month and the second line is supposed to be the day of the month.  I used a pivot table so that information could be updated and replicates would be removed.  When I updated the pivot table, a line early in the pivot table was added due to new information and now all the textboxes are showing incorrect information.

Is there any way with pivot tables that I can prevent this from happening and keep the correct information showing in the textboxes or is there another way I can do this?

This is the first image where the initial situation is:
[image: 1]

This is the second image, where the pivot table was updated and the textboxes in the figures are now not showing the desired information:
[image: 2]

Comment: I didn't mention this, but the textbox references are references like this to the cell the information is coming from:  $D$2

Comment: How are you choosing which day to display? In most cases you are choosing the smallest date in the data. But in other cases it's not (Dec 15), or you have selected more than one (April). If there is a rule, we can fix this so your rule is followed, but I can't infer it from what's in the post.